# Thermal Operations Characterization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information

In quantum thermodynamics, allowed operations (free transformations in the sense of resource theories) are usually defined via unitaries $U$ that leave the Gibbs state $e^{-\beta H}/Z$ ($Z=\text{Tr}\, e^{-\beta H}$) on system S and bath B invariant:

$U [e^{-\beta H_S}/Z_S \otimes e^{-\beta H_B}/Z_B] U^\dagger= e^{-\beta H_S}/Z_S \otimes e^{-\beta H_B}/Z_B\quad(=e^{-\beta(H_S\otimes \mathbb{I}_B+\mathbb{I}_S\otimes H_B)}/Z_SZ_B)$

In a review it was stated that this equality is equivalent to

$e^{-\beta U(H_S+H_B)U^\dagger}= e^{-\beta(H_S+H_B)}$,

yet somehow I am unable to reproduce this equivalence.
How does $U$ end up in the exponential? I tried via series expansion, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that $U$ is a unitary and for a given operator $A$, one has the following property

\begin{equation}
Uf(A)U^{\dagger} = f(U A U^{\dagger}) \, .
\end{equation}

As you pointed out $H_s \in \mathcal{H}_s$ while $H_B \in \mathcal{H}_B$, thus $[H_s, H_B] = 0$. Now, it's required that

\begin{equation}
U (\gamma_s \otimes \gamma_B) U^\dagger = \gamma_s \otimes \gamma_B \, .
\end{equation}

Using the above property, we can rewrite the left-hand-side and the expression becomes

\begin{equation}
e^{-\beta U(H_s + H_B)U^{\dagger}} = \gamma_s \otimes \gamma_B \, .
\end{equation}

In order to satisfy this equation, $U$ must commute with the total Hamiltonian of the system and bath, $[U, H+H_B] = 0$.

Comment: Thank you Alex, but assuming this property is not allowed at that stage - in fact the author of the review uses above equivalence to show (!) that $U$ must be energy-preserving.

Comment: I think you are mentioning the Lostaglio's review: "An introductory review of the resource theory approach to thermodynamics", right? If is it so, notice that the requirement to have $U \gamma_S \otimes \gamma_B U^{\dagger} = \gamma_S \otimes \gamma_B$ imples in $[U, H+ H_B]$. Therefore, this condition is not derived, but it is something that has to be true, otherwise, $U$ is not an energy-preserving unitary.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about this review. And sure, the requirement of preservation of Gibbs-state implies energy-preservation by $U$, but this implication is exactly what the author tries to show via above equivalence: “to prevent this, we require $U [e^{-\beta H_S}/Z_S \otimes e^{-\beta H_B}/Z_B] U^\dagger= e^{-\beta H_S}/Z_S \otimes e^{-\beta H_B}/Z_B$ which can be equivalently written as $e^{-\beta U(H_S+H_B)U^\dagger}= e^{-\beta(H_S+H_B)}$ WHICH IMPLIES $[H_S+H_B,U]=0$“.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid that I didn't understand your question, because the equivalence of $e^{-\beta U(H_S+H_B)U^\dagger}= e^{-\beta(H_S+H_B)}$ implies in $[H_S+H_B,U]=0$...

Comment: Indeed, so this implication is not the issue. My question was about the initial equivalence before energy-preservation by $U$ is shown. The unitary (so far not assumed to be energy-preserving) is put into the exponential (how is this justified ?) and THEN shown to be energy-preserving. This is my problem

Comment: I'm sorry @quantumorsch, for some reason I thought you were asking why $[H_S+H_B,U]=0$ should hold not about the initial equivalence between the two expressions. I've just edited my answer - hope it fits for you. Thanks, Alex!

Comment: Thank you very much Alex, the first property is the one I was missing - somehow it had left my brain. No idea why, sorry!